Flask-Breadcrumbs - different breadcrumbs in same Routes.py
I am trying to implement Flask-Breadcrumbs (for location breadcrumbs) on a fairly simple site, something like the following:
Home
|- Stock
|   |- Wood
|   |- Kits
|   |- Consumables
(Edit: This does not come out as I typed: basically, level 1 is Home, level 2 is Stock and level 3 includes Wood, Kits and Consumables)
So, I have set the routes (see below) and everything works until I get to the top level, where whichever page I am on the breadcrumb (and associated link) is always for the last route defined (e.g., I could be on the Wood page, but the breadcrumbs read Home>Stock>Consumables.
@bp.route('/')
@register_breadcrumb(bp, '.', 'Stock')
@login_required
def stock_home():
  ...

@bp.route('/timber')
@register_breadcrumb(bp, '.Stock', 'Timber')
@login_required
def timber():
  ...

@bp.route('/kits')
@register_breadcrumb(bp, '.Stock', 'Kits')
@login_required
def kits():
  ...

@bp.route('/consumables')
@register_breadcrumb(bp, '.Stock', 'Consumables')
@login_required
def consumables():
  ...

I've tried reading through the Flask-Breadcrumbs documentation and git pages, but cannot find any reference to more than one breadcrumb on the same level.
Any help gratefully received.
